# "Projections to..." meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Read the following statement.

> The graph below gives information about cinema attendance in Australia between 1990 and the present, with projections to 2010.

I'm confused with "Projections to 2010", Can someone please make it clear? Web's empty!

Comment: Presumably the graph and comments were published before 2010.

Comment: Projections to means up to some date, but doesn't state whether they include it specially. You can tell by looking at the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**project**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/project) (v): 1. Estimate or forecast (something) on the basis of present trends.

A *projection* is therefore a *forecast* or an *estimate* of future possibility.  In this case the graph uses existing data from 1990 to the "present" to *project* the trend forward to 2010.

It sounds strange in this context because, at the moment, 2010 is in the past.  We have to assume the sentence is from something that was written before 2010.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense..Yes, it was written before 2010

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that? Where is the graph? It seems that "the present" used in your sentence was a few years back.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**projection**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/projection)

> a calculation or guess about the future based on information that you have

[**to**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to) preposition (UNTIL)

> until a particular time, state, or level is reached

**projections to 2010** indicate that estimations for future values go from present to 2010 in the graph. 2010 is the temporal upper limit.